# MySQL SELECT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to get some data from a database, using MySQL JOIN, but with no success until now

I have table_a (representing order lines):

```
id  idc cPos
1   1   10
2   1   20
3   1   30
4   1   40
5   1   50
6   2   10
7   2   20
8   2   30
9   2   40
10  3   10
11  3   20
12  3   30
13  3   40
14  3   50
```

And table_b:

```
delivery_id idc cPos
1           1   10
1           1   50
2           1   20
2           3   40
2           3   50
```

I would like a query with the below results:

```
id  idc cPos    delivery_id
1   1   10      1
3   1   30      NULL
4   1   40      NULL
5   1   50      1
6   2   10      NULL
7   2   20      NULL
8   2   30      NULL
9   2   40      NULL
10  3   10      NULL
11  3   20      NULL
12  3   30      NULL
```

I need all records from table_b where delivery_id equals 1 and all records from table_a that don't have a corespondent in table_b (by corespondent I understand table_a.idc = table_b.idc AND table_a.cPos = table_b.cPos)

The query used by me:

```
SELECT table_a.*, table_b.delivery_id FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN table_b ON (table_a.idc = table_b.idc AND table_a.cPos = table_b.cPos)
WHERE (delivery_id IS NULL OR delivery_id = 1)
```

Could someone help me?

Comment: please add what you have tried

Comment: i updated the question with the query

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/24642/2/0 - **your** query listed above gives **your** required results ... so what is the question here ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create LEFT JOIN with 2 conditions:

```
SELECT tab_a.*,tab_b.delivery_id
FROM table_a tab_a
LEFT JOIN table_b tab_b ON tab_a.idc=tab_b.idc, tab_a.cPos=tab_b.cPos
```

Comment: @rosuandreimihai you don't have primmary key in table_b?

Comment: in the real tables there are primmary keys

Comment: I recreated part of your table and query that you use looks working correctly. What it's missing?

Comment: I don't understand your problem. The query is fine. Can you give us your real table structure?

Comment: @JoseAyram: I need all records from table_b where delivery_id equals 1 and all records from table_a that don't have a corespondent in table_b (by corespondent I understand table_a.idc = table_b.idc AND table_a.cPos = table_b.cPos)

Comment: @rosuandreimihai Exactly, your query is fine. What is your result? I tried with this data and structure and it's fine. Maybe a problem with the table structure?